# Catch and redirect click event from asp:Panel to asp:LinkButton within asp:ListView

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Ok I have a `asp:ListView` with each item wrapped up in a `asp:Panel` (`div`). I have added a handler for the `OnClick` event on the `asp:Panel` to redirect the click to a `asp:LinkButton` where this should trigger the `itemCommand` event handler.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ddtvMediaLib" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" class="list-group" OnItemCommand="ddtvMediaLib_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="ddtvMediaLib_ItemDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanging="ddtvMediaLib_SelectedIndexChanging">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Panel ID="ddtvMediaLibPanel" CssClass="list-group-item no-arrow" runat="server" Style="padding: 0">    
                                        <asp:Panel runat="server" Id="pnlSelect" CssClass="item-details" onClick="$('btnSelect').Click();">
                                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSelect" Visible="false" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Select" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                  </asp:Panel>                                        
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
```

My problem is that when I click on the `asp:Panel` it is not running the `itemCommand` event for the `asp:ListView` - any help appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your code (Change onclick to onclientclick) and register the script in codebehind.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" Id="pnlSelect" CssClass="item-details" onClientClick="$('btnSelect').Click();">
                                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSelect" Visible="false" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CommandName="Select" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                  </asp:Panel>
```